# zipping the files in unix having extension after

Tags: unix

I have a logs file at directory cd /opt/app/logs  named as

```
 coa.log.1
 uoa.log.2
 erete-rere.log.1
```

now my concern is that i am looking for unix command which will zip the files having extension log.1 or log.2 or having log. extension anything 
request you to please advise the unix comand to  zip these files

Folks please advise for this

Comment: Are you looking for `zip zipfile.zip *.log.*` ?

Comment: Pattern is *. log. *

Answer (score 0):

You can compress in a lot of formats in unix. The most commom is the `tar.gz` extension. If you are looking fot `.zip` specifically, there is a `zip` command: `zip <zipname> <files>`

To pass the file list you may use the `*` wirldcard, indicating any name. For example: `*.log.*`, as sugested by glen, will match every file that contains `.log.` in its name.

You probably want something like this:

`zip backup_logs.zip  /opt/app/logs/*.log.*`

This will zip all files in the folder that matched what you asked and create a zip file in your current directory.